# Following a tutorial: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks, redux-thunk

here i am returning a jsx element the element renders and API is hitting but when i use product.name it's returning undefined

```
import { useAlert } from 'react-alert';

import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';

import { getProductDetails, clearErrors } from '../../actions/productActions';

const ProductDetails = ({ match }) => {

    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const alert = useAlert();

    const { loading, error, product } = useSelector(state => state.productDetails)
    
    useEffect(() => { 

        dispatch(getProductDetails(match.params.id));
        
        if (error) {

            alert.error(error);

            dispatch(clearErrors());
        }
        
    }, [dispatch, alert, error, match.params.id])
    
return(console.log(product.name))
```

Comment: Please include all relevant code you've an issue working with in your question. Can we see your `productDetails` reducers and the `getProductDetails` action creator? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are dispatching `getProductDetails()` after your first render, which basically means that you are calling the API after your component is mounted.

`useEffect(() => {},[])` runs after first render of React component, and when you are trying to access `product.name`, product is actually undefined because the API isn't even called in the first place.

A solution would be to show a fallback loading screen, until you are finished loading. Make sure loading state is handled correctly though.

```
const ProductDetails = ({ match }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const alert = useAlert();

  const { loading, error, product } = useSelector(
    (state) => state.productDetails
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getProductDetails(match.params.id));

    if (error) {
      alert.error(error);

      dispatch(clearErrors());
    }
  }, [dispatch, alert, error, match.params.id]);

  if (loading) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }

  return <div>{product.name}</div>;
};
```